# mysql_fetch_array problem

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to do a guestbook in php but i am having some problems with **mysql_fetch_array** function. I don't understand why. I try to debug by putting 
**die("Error ".mysql_error())** but nothing prints out. I guarantee that all my variables are correctly initialized.
Here is my code :

```
<?php

 $nbmessagesPP = 10;
 mysql_connect(HOST, USER,PASSWORD) or die( "Unable to connect to database");
 mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

 .......

 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
  } else {
    $page = 1;
  }
  $first_msg = ($page - 1) * $nb_of_Page;
  $query = 'Select * from livredor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$first_msg.', '.$nbmessagesPP;
  $rep = mysql_query($query) or exit("Error in query".mysql_error());

  $v = true;
  while($v){
      $v = ($data = mysql_fetch_array($rep) or die ("Error fetching the data : ".mysql_error()));
      echo "<p>id -> ".$data['id']."</p>";    
      echo "<p>pseudo ->".$data['pseudo']."</p>";
      echo "<p>messages ->".$data['message']."</p>";
      echo "<hr/>";
  } 
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Can someone help me ;)

Comment: *i am having some problems with mysql_fetch_array* | **which problems?** Not sure but try to do it like everyone does: `while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rep)) {}`

Comment: maybe not have
 data in the table ?

Comment: "while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rep)) {}". When i do this, i cannot run my script, in firefox it said that the connection was reset by ther server. I know it is a bad way, but this is the only way i am using  to display my values.

Comment: I remember having this error :
"mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't deal with errors or the last row correctly. When `$v` is false, it still goes on to print some data. It would be better rewritten as:

```
while (($data = mysql_fetch_array($rep))) {    
  echo   
  ... 
}
```

That forces the evaluation of the fetch before moving on to the printing.

Comment: yeah i know, but when i put it in the while loop, i cannot even run my script. In firefox, it says that the connection was reset by the server.

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis there.

Comment: @You: intended... I always put extra parenthesis when using an assignment as part of a comparison. In this case it doesn't matter much,  but if it was ( (x=y) == 5) it makes a big difference.

Comment: In that case you're missing one. There's three `(` and only two `)` ;)

Comment: @You: lol... I went to fix it last time, said, "wait, no I meant that", and didn't even notice it was still wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access elements of the result that don't exist. `mysql_fetch_array` returns a regular array, with integer indices. What you want is `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which returns an associative array.

**Edit:** You also have the problem Chris describes, not dealing with the last row correctly.

Comment: I still have the same probl by using mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: I remember having this error : "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're receiving an error saying "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" it means that your MySQL query has failed, therefor not returning a valid result resource.

Try to echo out `$query` before sending it through `mysql_query()`, then try placing the echo'd query into phpMyAdmin and see if it returns any results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found the problem. 
The problem was that in another page i had a mysql_connection and in that page i was creating a new one. 
I just catch the return value of mysql_connect function and then close it with mysql_close function at the end.  Like this :

```
  <?php
     $link = mysql_connect(HOST, USER,PASSWORD) or die( "Unable to connect to database");
     mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 
     .....

     while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rep)) {//i do something here}

     mysql_close($link);    
 ?>
```

Thanks for your answers folks :)